# How best to enable a web service consumer to integration test a transactional web service?

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing

I want to allow consumers of a web services layer (web services are written in Java) to create automated integration tests to validate that the version of the web services layer that the consumers will use will still work for the consumer (i.e. the web services are on a different release lifecycle than the consumers and their APIs or behavior might change-- they shouldn't change wihtout notifying the consumer, but the point of this automated test is to validate that they haven't changed)

What would I do if the web service actually executes a transaction (updates database tables). Is there a common practice for how to handle this without having to put logic into the web service itself to know its in a unit test and rollback the transaction once finished? (basically baking in the capability to deal with testing of the web service). Or is that the recommended way to do it?

The consumers are created by one development team at our company and the web services are created by a seperate team. The tests would run in an integration environment (the integration environment is one environment behind the test environment used by QA functional testers, one environment behind the prod environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this sort of thing is [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Put your database handling code in a service or services that are injected into the webservice, and create mock versions that are used in your testing environment and do not actually update a database, or in which you add capability of reset under test control.

This way your tests can exercise the real webservices but not a real database, and the tests can be more easily made repeatable.

Dependency injection in Java can be done using (among others) [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).  Guice is a bit more lightweight.

It may be sensible in your situation to have the injection decision made during application startup based on a system property as you note.

If some tests need to actually update a database to be valid, then your testing version of the database handling will need to use a real database, but should also provide a way accessible from tests to reset your database to a known (possibly empty) state so that tests can be repeated.

Comment: I ideally dont want to have to modify the deployed artifacts between test environments and production (to modify what is injected) or use a separate tool to do DI e.g. Spring (unless there is something extremely lightweight that I can easily deploy). I could add a check in the code to check a system property and if we're in the test environment, then the instance of the web service that will be created will be the test instance. Good/bad idea? And what if I truly do want to execute the db transaction? (there are cases where I must execute it in order to be a valid test)

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to host the web services layer in production and in pre-production. Your customers can test against pre-production, but won't get billed for their transactions.

Obviously, this requires you to update production and pre-production at the same time.

Comment: Thanks-- please see additional context in the third paragraph.

Comment: Maybe you can define some version number in the WSDL and have the team that develops the consumer systems check for that version number?

Answer (score 0):

Let the web services run unchanged and update whatever they need to in the database.

Your integration tests should check that the correct database records have been written/updated after each test step.
We use a soapUI testbed to accomplish this.
You can write your post-test assertion scripts in Groovy and Java, which can easily connect to the db using JDBC and check records.

People get worried about using the actual database - I wouldn't get hung up on this, it's actually a GOOD thing and makes for a really accurate testbed.
Regarding the "state" of the db, you can approach this in a number of ways:

- Restore a db in a known state before the tests run
- Get the test to cleanup after themselves
- Let the db fill up as more tests run and clean it out occassionally

We've taken the last approach for now but may change in future if it becomes problematic.
I actually don't mind filling the db up with records as it makes it even more like a real customer database. It also is really useful when investigating test failures.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. cxf allows you to change the transport layer. so you can just change the configuration and use localTransport. then you can have to objects: client and server without any network activity. it's great for testing (un)marhasling. everything else should be separated so the business logic is not aware of webservices so it can be tested as any other class